# Change IDs of existing categories in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am newbie to magento. I managed to import the categories to one of my magento setup. I have imported about 300 categories successfully. But the problem is the new categories have been created with new category IDs. So I have export the category using this [quick script](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quick-script-to-export-categories-with-ids/)
Now I wanted to know that if there is a way to change existing categories ID with the csv I have export. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Find and replace in your `CSV` file should do the trick before importing the file to the new installation.